# Передача php -переменной в файл сss

Tags: php

привет можно как-нибуть передать ?

```
<?php $color='red' ?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="link_css.css" >
link_css.css
p{color:<? echo $color ?>}
```

Comment: Не занимайтесь ерундой! Передать в css файл переменную. Уже давно многие пользуются чем-то подручным, чем-то что более подходит для изменения цвета для абзаца. @Jim_Moriarty его ответ, думаю, вполне правильный. Но заданный вопрос - не претендует на решение вообще. Такого лучше не делать (Это исходя именно из вопроса!)

Comment: +1 лучше так не делать вообще

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1 вариант. Используйте вместо css-файла php-файл. Добавьте в начало php-файла отправку хэдера:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

Подключается как обычный css-файл, не инклудом:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.php" />
```

Но. Не работает в IE.

2 вариант. Обрабатывайте css-файлы как php. Добавьте в свой .htaccess такие строки:

```
<Files style.css>
  ForceType application/x-httpd-php
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css
</Files>
```

[Файл stype.css будет обрабатываться как файл PHP](http://www.geekhelpguide.com/php/handle-images-css-js-php-httpd-conf-using-htaccess/). Подключается как обычно:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам.

Comment: в любом из приведённых примеров советую позаботиться о кешировании, хотя бы с клиентской стороный

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, вам нужно вот это 
`<p style="color:<?echo $color?>">Text...</p>`

Comment: Про этот способ я знаю.Спасибо за внимание к вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Правильней будет использовать разные классы, названия которых подставлять в шаблон с помощью php

```
<p class="<?php echo $class;?>">Text...</p>
```

или с определенной логикой:

```
<p class="<?php echo (условие) ? $class1 : $class2;?>">Text...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Разовью тему, начатую [@khvorostin](/users/7295/khvorostin) . Подключаем стиль с указанием параметра цвета

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="link_css.css?color=red" >
```

а в link_css.css

```
p{color:<?=$_GET['color'];?>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если таких динамических стилей не много, можно добавить их прямо в HTML через тег style в head секции. Тогда не надо будет обрабатывать css файлы как php.